# SUBMIT button is not sending mails when used under checkout "shipping method" page in magento

Tags: magento

please visit http://steel.newtrendzonline.com/

visit and buy some products, In checkout page, in 3rd step 3) Shipping Method,

we added the comment box, but below the "SUBMIT button" is not working.

The same code for "submit button" , which we used in "Contact form page" is working.

[mails are sending to contacts "e-mail"] . But the  "submit" button code" is not working

under 3)Shipping method in Checkout. [mails are not sending to contacts "e-mail"].

I edited the shipping_method.phtml file in proper way. Is there anything else i have to do?

please give me the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shipping method step is already using a `form` tag, so you can't use nested form, for now if you click the submit button of contact us it will action the shipping method form.

There are two solutions:

1. Either rewrite the onepage checkout controller and amend the shipping method action to send the emails.
2. Or use an ajax script and apply onClick event on the submit button to save the contact us details or send emails. Moreover, instead of using button type as `submit` use `button` so it doesn't trigger the shipping methods form action.

Hope you will get the idea.

If you are new to Magento, here is a simple solution:

```
<script>function submitContactus(){
        var name = $('name').value;
        var email = $('email').value;
        var telephone= $('telephone').value;
        var comment= $('comment').value;
        new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getUrl("contacts/index/post",array('_secure'=>true))?>',{
            parameters:{name:name,email:email,telephone:telephone,comment:comment},
            method:"post",
            onSuccess:function(this){
                 $('messagediv').update('Your message');
            }
      });
    }</script>
```

add the above script within the code of the contact us form and then update your button as

```
<button type='button' onclick='submitContactus()' class='button'>Submit</button>
```

Add a div anywhere you want to show the messages `<div id="messagediv" class""></div>`

Hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your reply.

I am new to magento. So i don't have knowledge in step 1.

This is my code below for button to send e-mails. it's working fine in contact form but not in shipping method. Can you please edit the code to  use ajax and onclick event, so i can send e-mails using submit button.

<div class="buttons-set">
<p class="required">&nbsp;</p>
<input id="hideit" style="display: none !important;" type="text" name="hideit" value="" /> <button class="button" title="&lt;?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')-&gt;__('Submit') ?&gt;" type="submit"></button></div>

Comment: Hi, I added your code in shipping_method.phtml. after that i entered submit button under shipping method,  nothing displayed, but when i checked mail id " yes, it was there. comments are sending to mail-id. I struggled for this too much. as i am editing module, I thought i had to edit some xml files. but you gave simply the best solution. thanks a lot.

Comment: have updated the answer, check the updated script and the idea of additional div

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately, it's not working me. I placed alert("welcome"); after method:"post", now i got pop up message. thanks a lot. i got another problem, after i click "continue" in 1)Billing information , mouse cursor going to 3)shipping method, instead of 2)shipping information, what mistake happened?

Comment: i placed an order, it worked for me, you might not be selecting ship to different address option at the bottom of billing section.

Comment: hi, you are right.i have another problem , In contact us page If i click "submit", without entering values for name ,email => i am getting message" This is required field", but " inside shipping method, if i click on  "submit " button, i am not getting any message, but comment is delivering to mail-id. can you please help me in finding solution.